# How do zonealarm and other security software stop internet activity?

Tags: internet

I always need to keep my PC on to do some calculation. I have an experience which people hack into my PC during late evening. I want to stop all internet activity to reduce the risk. Basically I can disconnect my internet cable. However, I don't want to do it every single day. I would like to use software to stop internet.

If I use software to stop internet, does it as safe as remove my internet cable?

Comment: what's you Operating System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `some software` or `disable by software`, your network board would not communicate over the wire so **yes**, it's as safe as removing the cable for this reason.

Even easier would be to disable your network interface or connection.